# openni_tracker displaying pointcloud and skeleton alignment?

Tags: kinect, openi-tracker, openni-kinect, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have openni_tracker working. However, I am not sure how I can visualize both point cloud from Kinect as well as the skeleton TF data.

I can visualize Kinect point cloud by setting fixed frame to /camera_link

And I can visualize TF skeleton data by setting fixed frame to /openni_depth_frame.

When I visualize TF data, there is no connection between point cloud related TF and skelecton related TF data. Am I doing something wrong?

How could I align these together?

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55827/openni_tracker-displaying-pointcloud-and-skeleton-alignment?/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest solution would be to launch the `openni_launch` with the `camera` argument set.  See the documentation at the bottom of [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch).  So the following command

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch camera:=openni
```

will set the first word of all of the frames associated with your Kinect to be "openni" instead of "camera". This should merge your `tf` tree.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-12**:
@jarvisschultz would you recommend openni_tracker for people detection?? Or do you know ay good stack that would acommplish people detection? Thanks

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-09-12**:
@ctguell if all you wanted to do was detect people, you could use openni_tracker, but it might be a bit overkill. If you still wanted to use a depth camera, maybe you could adapt openni_tracker a bit e.g. see the `User_NewUser` callback in the openni_tracker source.

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-08-13**:
As of 1.7, PCL now has pretty good people detection built in, if that's really what you want (as opposed to human pose estimation). Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/ground_based_rgbd_people_detection.php